# Thymeleaf layout dialect and th:replace in head causes title to be blank

Tags: layout, thymeleaf, dialect

I'm following this tutorial: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/layouts.html (got to Thymeleaf Layout Dialect section).
In there you can find an example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
  <!--/*  Each token will be replaced by their respective titles in the resulting page. */-->
    <title layout:title-pattern="$DECORATOR_TITLE - $CONTENT_TITLE">Task List</title>
    ...
  </head>
  <body>
    <!--/* Standard layout can be mixed with Layout Dialect */-->
    <div th:replace="fragments/header :: header">
    ...
    </div>
    <div class="container">
      <div layout:fragment="content">
      ...
      </div>
      <div th:replace="fragments/footer :: footer">&copy; 2014 The Static Templates</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Footer and header are replaced by `th:replace` tag in above example, while `<head>` has `<title>` tag in layout file.

Basically, I want to replace whole `<head>` tag with `th:replace`.
Therefore, I have:

My layout file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head th:replace="/html/components/head :: head">
</head>
<body>
     <div layout:fragment="content">
     </div>
...
     <div th:replace="/html/components/footer :: footer" />
</body>
<html>
```

My content file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html layout:decorator="/html/layouts/layout">
<head>
    <title>My content title</title>
</head>
<body>
      <div layout:fragment="content">
      ...
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

And finally my /html/components/head.htm file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout">
<head th:fragment="head">
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title layout:title-pattern="$CONTENT_TITLE">Layout Title should be replaced by Content Title!</title>
...
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Content is alright. Footer and head are included (replaced) from files as expected but page title is blank!

I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title></title>
...
```

What's wrong?

Comment: If I simply remove <head th:replace="/html/components/head :: head"> and I put content of the head file directly to layout.htm then title works. But I don't like ugliness of this solution. Is there any way to move whole head section and separate it from layout?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Finally, I've found a way to achieve what I wanted.

In layout file `<title>` tag **must** stay. All other tags I grouped with `<object>` tag and annotated it as follows:

```
<head>
  <title layout:title-pattern="$CONTENT_TITLE">Layout Title will be replaced by Page Title!</title>
  <object th:include="/html/components/head :: head" th:remove="tag" />
</head>
```

In my html/components/head.htm file I had to remove `<title>` tag so it won't be duplicated after include.

```
<head th:fragment="head">
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <!-- NO TITLE TAG HERE -->
  ...
</head>
```

This way head fragment is **included** in `<object>` tag and thanks to `th:remove="tag"` `<object>` tag gets removed and my final HTML output is:

```
<head>
  <title>My content title</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <!--  NO TITLE TAG HERE -->
  ...
</head>
```

Obviously, I removed NO TITLE TAG HERE message too, once I got it working.

Comment: I suggest you use `<meta th:include="/html/components/head :: head" th:remove="tag" />` since some IDE (e.g. IntelliJ) will flag the tag `object` as not allowed within `head`.

Comment: You can also use `<div th:replace="/html/components/head :: head" />`, this will have the same effect.

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much))

Answer (score 7):

I think I found a slightly less verbose way to for using `th:replace` and `th:fragment` together, e.g. to include common `<head>` metadata and static resource includes in your pages.

Put the `th:remove="tag"` in the **fragment definition**, so you don't have to repeat the `th:remove="tag"` everytime including it.

*fragment_head.html*

```
<thymeleaf xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" 
    th:fragment="head" th:remove="tag">

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/css/vendor/bootstrap.min.css}"/>

</thymeleaf>
```

*mypage.html*

```
<head>
    <thymeleaf th:replace="fragment_head :: head" />
</head>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can replace whole head tag.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head lang="pl" th:replace="fragments/head :: head">
</head>
<body>
 ...
</body>
</html>
```

resources/templates/fragments/head.html:

```
    <head lang="pl">
        <title>Title</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <link href="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"
              th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css}"
              rel="stylesheet" media="screen" />

        <script src="http://cdn.jsdelivr.net/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js"
                th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js}"></script>
        <link href="../static/css/mycss.css"
              th:href="@{css/mycss.css}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen"/>
    </head>
```