# Thymeleaf - Include content of fragment

Tags: java, templates, layout, thymeleaf

Thymeleaf fragment:

```
<div th:fragment="assets">
    <script src="myscript"></script>
    <script src="myscript2"></script>
</div>
```

This piece of code inserts the fragment:

```
<div th:replace="fragments/assets :: assets"></div>
```

How to include only content without the wrapper?

```
<script src="myscript"></script>
<script src="myscript2"></script>
```

Comment: @BalajiKrishnan I din't get it. Could you be more specific?

Comment: @kidwon This has been a very simple and elegant solution. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try the below

```
<div th:fragment="assets" th:remove="tag">
    <script src="myscript"></script>
    <script src="myscript2"></script>
</div>
```

Comment: ref: http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.pdf page:46. This should remove the wrapper tag

Answer (score 16):

You can use th:block to include only content of a block.

Define your fragment like -

```
<th:block th:fragment="assets">
    <script src="myscript"></script>
    <script src="myscript2"></script>
</th:block>
```

And include like this -

```
<th:block th:include="fragments/assets :: assets"></th:block>
```

Hope this will help you :)

Comment: Thank you, sir! This method was very helpful for me!

Answer (score 3):

Use this:

```
<div id="testId" th:include="fragments/assets :: assets"></div>
```

It will also insert the specified fragment as the body of its with in outer tag but excluding the fragment tag.

Answer (score 1):

The best way I've found to handle the script tag case is to use [Thymeleaf Layouts](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#template-layout) since fragments are always nested inside a tag when using th:include or th:replace.

Further, one useful approach I use is to add the common scripts as normal at the bottom of a layout template and then add a final script content block e.g:

```
  ...
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <div layout:fragment="script"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Then pages which use the template can specify any extra javascript in a "script" block:

```
<script th:inline="javascript" layout:fragment="script" type="text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
  // Some javascript...
/*]]>*/
```

Answer (score 1):

Yout Thymeleaf fragment:

```
<div th:fragment="assets" th:remove="tag">
    <script src="myscript"></script>
    <script src="myscript2"></script>
</div>
```

Your code insert of the fragment:

```
<div th:replace="fragments/assets :: assets"></div>
```

This should render like:

```
<script src="myscript"></script>
<script src="myscript2"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like to pass some parameters to the script, you can to like this (Google reCaptchaV3 example):

in your HTML, do this:

```
<th:block th:include="fragments/script-google-recaptcha-submit.html :: on-submit(form = 'contact-form')"></th:block>
```

in your 'script-HTML', do this:

```
<th:block th:fragment="on-submit">
    <script th:inline="javascript">
        /*<![CDATA[*/

        function onSubmit(token) {
            console.log(/*[[${form}]]*/);
            document.getElementById(/*[[${form}]]*/).submit();
        }

        /*]]>*/
    </script>
</th:block>
```