# How to use Thymeleaf Fragment and Replace tags to insert css inside html file

Tags: java, html, css, thymeleaf

I need to insert these code every html in the folder, so am trying to insert it inside head tag using thymeleaf:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/assets/css/plugins.css">
<!-- Bootstap CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/assets/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Main Style CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/assets/css/style.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../static/assets/css/responsive.css">
```

Comment: Have you tried to [implement a fragment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69710440/how-to-use-thymeleaf-fragment-and-replace-tags-to-insert-css-inside-html-file/69712041#69712041) for yourself? If so, what happened? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: There are also tutorials such as [this one](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-thymeleaf-fragments) - and others. There are also various SO questions ([one example here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35988081/thymeleaf-include-content-of-fragment)).

Comment: Here is the correct [implement a fragment](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf#including-template-fragments) link.