# Thymeleaf apply different title-patterns

Tags: java, html, spring, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using the latest version of [thymeleaf page layouts](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html).

I want to use the title pattern `$CONTENT_TITLE - $LAYOUT_TITLE` for all my pages. Therefore, I created the following layout and content files.

My `layout.html` file looks like

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title layout:title-pattern="$CONTENT_TITLE - $LAYOUT_TITLE">My Company Name</title>
    <!-- some scripts and styles --->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- some content --->
</body>
</html>
```

My `content.html` looks like

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      layout:decorate="~{layout.html}">
<head>
    <title>
        <th:block th:if="${meta.pageTitle}" th:text="${meta.pageTitle}"></th:block>
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <!-- some content --->
</body>
</html>
```

If the content page gets `Newsletter` as value for the property `pageTitle` and I call the content page in my browser, I get the correct result:

```
<title>Newsletter - My Company Name</title>
```

If my content page does not have a title, I only want to display the `$LAYOUT_TITLE` in my `<title>` tag without the leading separator `-`. Howerver, with my code I get

```
<title>- My Company Name</title>
```

What I want is

```
<title>My Company Name</title>
```

How can I achieve that in a simple way? As far as I know, I cant use the `$CONTENT_TITLE` in the layout.html and check if it is empty, or can I?

Answer (score 0):

Since i could not find a way to use conditions for the title-pattern I moved away from this and used parameterizable fragments as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34727232/5885498).

`layout.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" xmlns:layout="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <!-- some scripts and styles --->
</head>
<body>
    <!-- some content --->
</body>
</html>
```

`content.html`

```
<!doctype html>
<html xmlns:layout="http://www.ultraq.net.nz/thymeleaf/layout" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org"
      layout:decorate="~{layout.html}">

<head>
    <th:block th:replace="./fragments/page-title.html :: page-title('My Content Title')"></th:block>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- some content --->
</body>
</html>
```

`./fragments/page-title.html`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head th:fragment="page-title(pageTitle)" th:remove="tag">
    <title th:text="(${pageTitle}? ${pageTitle} + ' - ' : '') + 'My Company Name'"></title>
</head>
</html>
```

This results in 
`<title>My Content Title - My Company Name</title>` for all pages with an additional title and `<title>My Company Name</title>` for all pages without an additional title (like my start page).

Answer (score 0):

Try simply to make your **$CONTENT_TITLE** have the "**Newsletter -**" value and in your layout.html put the following line to have a new title-pattern:

```
<title layout:title-pattern="$CONTENT_TITLE $LAYOUT_TITLE">My Company Name</title>
```

Comment: that's what I wanted to avoid because I dont want to set the dash "delimiter" on every page separately. The `-` should only be defined once like `My Company Name`